# How to select multiple checkboxes with SHIFT in tkinter?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

The question is quite simple,I've created many checkboxes in a Text widget using `window_create` .Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
sb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical")
text = tk.Text(root, width=40, height=20, yscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.config(command=text.yview)
sb.pack(side="right",fill="y")
text.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)
for i in range(30):
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(text="checkbutton %s" % i,padx=0,pady=0,bd=0)
    text.window_create("end", window=cb)
    text.insert("end", "\n") 

root.mainloop()
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image]

I want to select multiple checkboxes,which is troublesome if I have to click every checkbox.So is there a way that **SHIFT** can be used here?

Comment: Instead of a binding, have you considered adding a "select all" and "deselect all" button to do the same thing? Most users will never realize they can shift-click to select all, and you can't depend on them reading the user guide.

Comment: Yes,adding 'select all' and 'inverse select' button is in my plan.But sometimes using 'shift-select' will be better,for example you want to select several chunks of checkboxes.

Comment: @BryanOakley Could you take a look at the chosen answer? If change                `for cb in self.chkbuttons[sl]:
            cb.toggle()    `                                                  to                                                       `map(tk.Checkbutton.toggle, self.chkbuttons[self.start+1:end])`      it won't work and I don't know why.Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind the `'<Shift-Button-1>'` event to every checkbutton, and also the `'<Button-1>` to indicate the start of the range which should be selected. Also, consider to wrap your code in a class for better readability:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.start = 0
        self.root = root
        self.sb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical")
        text = tk.Text(root, width=40, height=20, yscrollcommand=self.sb.set)
        self.sb.config(command=text.yview)
        self.sb.pack(side="right",fill="y")
        text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.chkbuttons = [tk.Checkbutton(text="checkbutton %s" % i,padx=0,pady=0,bd=0)
                          for i in range(30)]                        
        for cb in self.chkbuttons:
            text.window_create("end", window=cb)
            text.insert("end", "\n")
            cb.bind("<Button-1>", self.selectstart)
            cb.bind("<Shift-Button-1>", self.selectrange)

    def selectstart(self, event):
        self.start = self.chkbuttons.index(event.widget)

    def selectrange(self, event):
        start = self.start
        end = self.chkbuttons.index(event.widget)
        sl = slice(min(start, end)+1, max(start, end))
        for cb in self.chkbuttons[sl]:
            cb.toggle()
        self.start = end

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works?But it helps more or less,thanks anyway

Comment: @laike9m Yes, most of this code is yous, I've only added `selectstart` and `selectrange`.

Comment: I make your code work by simply replace `map` with a for loop.I think `map` should also work,but it just dosen't.

Comment: @laike9m I have improved a bit the code and this time I've tried it. It should work without any problem.

Comment: Surely this works.But I still don't know what's wrong with the **`map`** function,after all it looks pretty nice using **`map`**

Comment: beware. this may result in exception if you click the text instead of the checkbutton